# LibGDX Tests Gradle not working: "Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application'] Project contains 2 or more modules with same identification"

Tags: android, libgdx

I just downloaded the LibGDX test sources as explained in the wiki (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Running-Tests)

If I try to run a test project of LibGDX, I receive that error message. How can I solve that?

[image]